# "TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined" occurs though the values computes correctly

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm really new to javascript and vue, and I've got the following problem.

Here I'd like to show all the value from Google Map API DistanceMatrix service, so this is the code in `computed ()`

```
places () {
  var idsToFind = this.$store.getters.loadedTrip(this.id).places
  var places = this.$store.state.loadedPlaces.filter(item => idsToFind.includes(item.id))
  var service = new google.maps.DistanceMatrixService()
  return places.map((place, i) => {
    var destination = this.$store.state.loadedPlaces.filter(item => idsToFind.includes(item.id)).slice(1)[i].name
    return {
      place: place,
      time: this.$store.getters.loadedTrip(this.id).timeEach[i],
      place2: this.$store.state.loadedPlaces.filter(item => idsToFind.includes(item.id)).slice(1)[i],
      durationTravelled: service.getDistanceMatrix({
        origins: [place.name],
        destinations: [destination],
        travelMode: 'TRANSIT'
      }, (response, status) => {
        var duration = response.rows[0].elements[0].duration.text
        console.log(duration)
        return duration
      })
    }
  })
}
```

Unfortunately, what I've got in console is

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined
```

However, when I console.log as I have shown the values show correctly as I expected in the console.

This problem prevents my page from being rendered and I've not been able to solve it.

The variable `places` contains the array of objects holding the data of certain places from my database. Moreover, I did `slice(1)` the array because I need the next object in that variable to be shown when I looped through it. Basically, I embedded the google map showing the direction from place A to B in modal, but I'd also like to show the duration taken for each travel before clicking on it.

I have console.log the variable "destination" shown in first 3 lines of the console, and the screenshot is added:

[image]

Line 194 refers to `place: place,`

Comment: so, which `.name` is the error referring to?

Comment: Looks like we're missing some code, since the beginning of that code is syntactically incorrect. Is there a `function` keyword missing? Also, which line is the problem with the TypeError? A few name properties are being accessed.

Comment: I think OP meant for `origins: [place.name],`

Comment: by the way `.slice(1)` will return an array that starts with the second item of the sliced array ... but then you're using `i` as an index into this new array ... that looks like very odd code, because it implies that the filtered `this.$store.state.loadedPlaces` array is always going to be at least `i + 1` long

Comment: @BhojendraNepal - why that one? I'm more inclined to think that a filter operation has resulted in an array that only has `i` or less items, and therefore `array.slice(1)[i]` results in `undefined` and hence the error - can't see why `place` would be `undefined` and the OP not knowing that

Comment: @JaromandaX I think place is undefined there since OP used arrow function.

Comment: @BhojendraNepal - what the heck does the arrow notation have to do with it? `this.$store.state.loadedPlaces` would have to have an item, that, *simultaneously*, has an `id` (that matches the criteria of the filter) **and** is `undefined` ... now, we all know that something can't be two different values at once, and `undefined` can't have a property at all, let alone one called `id` - so ... tell me again how `place` could possibly be `undefined`

Comment: oh, yeah, you're right

Comment: I have added more details in the post explaining what I'm trying to implement here.

Comment: can you provide a working example in codepen/jsfiddle? The problem may not be in the code your provided as no one seems to be able to find out what's wrong.